# A Cartesian model structure (and straightening for) on $n$-trivial simplicial sets

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

A pair $(X,tX)$, with $X$ a simplicial set and $tX$ a collection of simplices of $X$, is said to be stratified if no $0$-simplex is in $X$ and all degenerate simplices of $X$ are in $tX$. Recall a stratified simplicial set $X$ is $n$-trivial if $X=|X|_n$, the collection of $n$-simplices of $X$. This definition generalizes the notion of marked and scaled simplicial sets, see for example Verity's paper on [complicial sets](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410412v2.pdf), so that this obviously seems like a generalization of the notion of $\infty$ and $(\infty,2)$-categories. My questions are:

> - Is there a (left proper, combinatorial) Cartesian model structure on the category $\mathfrak{Strat}_n$ of $n$-trivial simplicial sets (see Example 102 of [another paper by Verity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604414.pdf)) such that the fibrant objects are precisely the $(\infty,n)$-categories, i.e., such that they satisfy the Barwick-Schommer-Pries axioms?
> - With this model structure, is there a suitable notion of straightening?

I can take a reasonable guess for the first question - let the cofibrations be the monomorphisms of the underlying simplicial sets, the weak equivalences the maps that are equivalences under a left adjoint to a suitable generalization of the [$\omega$-categorical nerve](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604414.pdf) to these $n$-trivial simplicial sets, and the fibrations the maps with the RLP with respect to the acyclic cofibrations.

Comment: If there *was* such a model structure, then I guess we could use Lurie's chunks (in particular Proposition T.4.2.4.4) to study straightening.